# Tests on jest and new Date()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test function similar on this:

```
function foo() {
    return {
        key_a: "val_a",
        key_b: new Date()
};
```

How can I make an expected object for test for this case?

```
const expectedObject = {
    key_a: "val_a",
    key_b: new Date()
}
expect(foo()).toEqual(expectedObject)?
- Expected
+ Received
- "key_b": 2019-01-23T14:04:03.060Z,
+ "key_b": 2019-01-23T14:04:03.061Z,
```

Comment: I guess you need to verify that date is in range

Comment: You should really spy on the `new Date` function (haven't used jest but presume you can as in jasmine), you only need to test it's the same function, not what it returns, you'd hope that's been tested already

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, maybe , but how i can be sure that my function returns me exactly what i want in this case ? I mean my main purpose is make sure that function will return exactly what i need... :)
Let's say it's just a small part data that returns from factory ^^

Comment: When you spy on the function, have it return something and check it returns what you expect - have a read up on it, spies are very powerful when it comes to testing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are various approaches to this, many are discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234).

Probably the most simple and clean approach in this case is to spy on `Date` and get what was returned from `new Date()` using [`mockFn.mock.instances`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances) like this:

```
function foo() {
  return {
    key_a: "val_a",
    key_b: new Date()
  };
}

test('foo', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'Date');  // spy on Date
  const result = foo();  // call foo
  const date = spy.mock.instances[0];  // get what 'new Date()' returned
  const expectedObject = {
    key_a: "val_a",
    key_b: date  // use the date in the expected object
  };
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedObject);  // SUCCESS
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This question showed up first in the google search and would like to add the "new" recommended way to do this supported by Jest, you can also find this in the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234#issuecomment-730037781) referred in Brian's answer. But putting here to save time for people searching for a solution:

```
const FIXED_SYSTEM_TIME = '2020-11-18T00:00:00Z';

describe('Set Fixed Date', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.useFakeTimers('modern');
        jest.setSystemTime(Date.parse(FIXED_SYSTEM_TIME));
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.useRealTimers();
    });
    
    it('Should reflect fixed date', () => {
        expect(new Date().toISOString()).toEqual(FIXED_SYSTEM_TIME);

        const MS_TO_ADVANCE = 5000;

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(MS_TO_ADVANCE);

        expect(new Date().toISOString()).toEqual(new Date(Date.parse(FIXED_SYSTEM_TIME) + MS_TO_ADVANCE).toISOString());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With dates sometimes it is enough to check that it is not null, in this case you may use `expect.anything()`

```js
expect(foo()).toEqual(expect.anything())

// examples:
expect(new Date()).toEqual(expect.anything()) // PASS
expect(null).toEqual(expect.anything()) // FAIL
expect(null).not.toEqual(expect.anything()) // PASS
```

[docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanything)